# How to make PhoneGap app go to home page?

Tags: cordova, html

I'm making a PhoneGap app, and at some parts they redirect to an actual website, instead of the local files.  When I close and reopen the app, it shows the last viewed page. I need it to go back to the home page when the app opens.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the InAppBrowser to launch external web links. This way when you open the external links and close the [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), it will go back to your application.

Check out the official docs on how to use it.

[InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Comment: Thank you for telling me about that-I'm just getting used to PG, and that helps a lot! :)